# Fluend record_transformer plugin not abel to remove key with forward slash

Tags: fluentd

I'm trying to remove a field using record_transformer plugin. The field has forward slash in it. I tried various way but nothing helped

```
<filter test.**>
      @type record_transformer
      enable_ruby true
      remove_keys $['kubernetes.namespace_labels.kubernetes.io/metadata.name']
      <record>
        lumberjack_log_group "horizon"
      </record>
    </filter>
```

I have tried:

```
$["kubernetes.namespace_labels.kubernetes.io\/metadata.name"]
"kubernetes.namespace_labels.kubernetes.io\\/metadata.name"
"kubernetes.namespace_labels.kubernetes.io\/metadata.name"
```

Can someone please provide me pointers on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation didn't do any good, I tried debugging it and managed to remove the keys when doing the following:
Hope it helps

Try this:

```
 # This Segment removed labels from log records
      # Add other labels to be removed here
      <filter containers.**>
        @type record_transformer
        remove_keys $['kubernetes']['labels']['app.kubernetes.io/name'],$['kubernetes']['labels']['app.kubernetes.io/component']
      </filter>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).